# Swift operators explanation

Tags: swift, operators, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to convert some Swift code into Javascript, but have hit a bump because I don't know what some of these operators in Swift do, so I can't convert it into it's analogous Javascript form. Here is the code:

```
private var portMasks = [UInt8](count: 3, repeatedValue: 0)

var newMask = UInt8(newState.rawValue * Int(powf(2, Float(pinIndex))))
portMasks[Int(port)] &= ~(1 << pinIndex) //prep the saved mask by zeroing this pin's corresponding bit
newMask |= portMasks[Int(port)] //merge with saved port state
portMasks[Int(port)] = newMask
data1 = newMask<<1; data1 >>= 1  //remove MSB
data2 = newMask >> 7 //use data1's MSB as data2's LSB
```

Where `pinIndex`, `port` have been defined already and are both `UInt8`.

I'm not looking for the actual conversion - I can do that myself. Just looking for an explanation of what each of these lines are doing from a mathematical/programmatic standpoint.

Comment: All Swift operators are well documented in the Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID28.

Comment: Thanks for this link! It has some of the operators but is missing `>>=` and `|=`

Comment: You did not post a question about Swift before at least browsing through the documentation, did you ? :)

Comment: @TyleratMaijlet `left >>= right` is equivalent to `left = left >> right`, and `left |= right` is equivalent to `left = left | right`.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new playground and copy this inside:

```
var port: UInt8 = 1
var pinIndex: UInt8 = 2
var newState: Int = 23

var portMasks = [UInt8](count: 3, repeatedValue: 0)

var newMask = UInt8(newState * Int(powf(2, Float(pinIndex))))
portMasks[Int(port)] &= ~(1 << pinIndex) //prep the saved mask by zeroing this pin's corresponding bit
newMask |= portMasks[Int(port)] //merge with saved port state
portMasks[Int(port)] = newMask
var data1 = newMask<<1; data1 >>= 1  //remove MSB
var data2 = newMask >> 7 //use data1's MSB as data2's LSB
```

You will see the effects on the right side.

```
<< >> move bits by that amount
| logical or
& logical and
~ logical negation
```

Think that's all what is used here. Basically your code is manipulating single bits (referenced by 1 << bitPosition) and either turning them on or off.

These two lines mean the same:

```
variable OPERATOR= something
variable = variable OPERATOR something
```

Would suggest to play around a little and then come back with specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for this! Let me go check this out